# Delphi / C++Builder properties of component handling of empty strings?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have a component with a `FileName` property derived from a base class.  The base class sets the `FileName` on `.Create`.  The component doesn't override the base class value if the property is blank.  If I set it to something other than blank, it overrides the base class value.

Stepping through and setting a break point on the `FileName` property where properties are set I noticed that the break point is only hit if I set a value and not hit if I leave it blank.

Does this mean internally Delphi/C++Builder only saves/stores properties that are not blank / empty strings so that when it's loading the properties it doesn't have one to use?

Is there something that controls that?

Comment: From which base class are you deriving?

Comment: Please show the actual code in a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean internally Delphi/C++Builder only saves/stores properties that are not blank / empty strings so that when it's loading the properties it doesn't have one to use?

That is correct.  Per the [Properties: Storage Specifiers](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Storage_Specifiers) documentation:

> If a property has no **stored** directive, it is treated as if stored **True** were specified.
>
> ...
>
> To override an inherited **default** value without specifying a new one, use the **nodefault** directive. The **default** and **nodefault** directives are supported only for ordinal types and for set types, provided the upper and lower bounds of the set's base type have ordinal values between 0 and 31; if such a property is declared without **default** or **nodefault**, it is treated as if **nodefault** were specified. For reals, pointers, and strings, there is an implicit default value of 0, nil, and '' (the empty string), respectively.
>
> ...
>
> When saving a component's state, the storage specifiers of the component's published properties are checked. If a property's current value is different from its **default** value (or if there is no **default** value) and the **stored** specifier is **True**, then the property's value is saved. Otherwise, the property's value is not saved.
>
> ***Note:** Property values are not automatically initialized to the default value. That is, the default directive controls only when property values are saved to the form file, but not the initial value of the property on a newly created instance.*

In other words, the default value for a string property is a blank string, and the property is not saved to the DFM if its current value is blank, or its `stored` directive evaluates as `False`.